# ContentPage Properties

Tags: xamarin

Is there any information regarding the list of the properties of a ContentPage (i.e. BackgroundColor, Padding, HorizonalOptions, etc.)? The documentation in Xamarin does not contain these information.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: they are documented, but most of the interesting properties are actually inherited from a parent class (ie, VisualElement), so you need to look further up the tree to find them.  https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage/#memberlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) said, the documentation from Xamarin is actually exhaustive, but some of the properties of the ContentPage class are inherited from superclasses ([Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Page/#memberlist), which inherits from [VisualElement](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement/) and so on). You should also check the documentation of these .